# How to get model property in className of ItemView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I my app I need to render ul of users with their ids in class attribute of li. S I tried to do it like this:

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: this.model.get('user_id'),
        template: userTpl
});
```

But it didn't work. Is it possible to achieve this some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you do something like this?

```
className: function(){
  return this.model.get('user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this logic to [onBeforeRender](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#beforerender--onbeforerender-event) method

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: userTpl,
    onBeforeRender: function(){
          this.className = this.model.get('user_id'),
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setElement`, [here's the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) :

> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use setElement, which will also create the cached $el reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

Comment: This id slightly different. I don't want to apply a view to a different element. The element gets created by Backbone. I just need to get the property of model to set a class name of that element.

Comment: You can't do it like this, because at the time Backbone create `$el` your `this.model.get('user_id')` is not yet set. So you have to either use `setElement` or just do `$el.addClass()`